# Ajax Requests don't work when other JS scripts are included in the html page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using an AJAX request to get some data fetched from the database. There are four `.js` files that I have included in the HTML page. They are

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jqueryui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/framework.plugins.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/custom.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".buttonid").click(
    function(){
          $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
            type: "POST",
            url: "php/fetch_candidates.php",
            async: true,             
            dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned   
            error: function(){
                    return true;
            },                       
            success: function(response){                    
                $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
                //alert(response);
            }
    });

    });
});
</script>
```

This doesn't work. But if I remove

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/framework.plugins.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/custom.js"></script>
```

then the AJAX starts working. How can I solve this as I need to keep all the `.js` files in the html page.

There is a responsecontainer div which handles the html afte rthe ajax request. The problem is only with including those two js scripts. TIA

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does it generate an error, is there no ajax request, does the request return an error? And what's inside those 2 JS files?

Comment: Is there js conflict issue?

Comment: Try placing the scripts after this ajax script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the other frameworks also use `$` function, it might override jQuery's `$` functional behaviour. But this leaves the `jQuery` variable untouched. So try using a closure and execute it inside an IIFE:

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".buttonid").click(function () {
      $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/fetch_candidates.php",
        async: true,             
        dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned   
        error: function(){
          return true;
        },                       
        success: function(response){                    
          $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
          //alert(response);
        }
      });
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

This will translate all the `$` into `jQuery`'s original function and make sure you use `$` with only jQuery and not any other framework like PrototypeJS or Scriptaculous.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But how do i do this with a click event. Tried with the following but hasn't worked

Comment: (function ($) {
  $("#category").click(function() {
  
      $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/fetch_candidates.php",
        async: true,             
        dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned   
        error: function(){
          return true;
        },                       
        success: function(response){                    
          $("#candidates_list").html(response); 
          //alert(response);
        }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);</script>

Comment: @GauravBora What's happening on the console? Any errors? Is the AJAX event firing at least?

Comment: Its working. It was a minor error. My bad. Thanks a lot Praveen.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `var jq = $.noConflict();` , just before the `$(".buttonid").click(`

and use `jq` instead of `$`, it looks like a conflict issue, can you please share what is inside the `framework.plugins.js` and `custom.js`

Comment: Hi Satpal, May I know why did you edit the answer, removed my characters and added the same characters back ?

Comment: @robindersingh1986 Can't you see how your answer looked before and after?

Comment: Ohh okay got it, My Bad. Thanks for pointing that. (Still Human at the end of day, missed the embossing)